# In core php how to share product title,image and description on social media?

Tags: share

In core php how to share product title, image and description on social media?
There are problem in sharing.
Sometime output with previous image or logo or unknown image.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}
```

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id={app_id}&display={page_type}&href={url}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other for the social network to get the image, name and description you need to add some meta tags to your html page. for example.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the page">
<meta property="og:description" content="Some Description of it.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain_dot_com/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://domain_dot_com//somePage.php">
```

Also some social networks like facebook cached your images and urls to make the image and load faster, in case that your post get share to a lot of users.

Comment: dear thanks for reply, i tried with this also but sometime in output data comes with wrong image or previous image,and description.   dynamic data pass.      i think it is catch problem

Comment: yes, try a different link, because facebook for example will cache your page info. I did mention it on the answer.